# How to extend a ELF binary

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, binary, elf

I am writing a small instrumentation tool. I must insert the instrumentation routine within the binary file. A good approach should be to insert those routines in a separate code segment and a separate data segment, could you explain how to accomplish this? Furthemore how can I modify the size of the code segment in the original file?

Best,

Comment: Why don't you do that at runtime using interposing? `LD_PRELOAD` on Linux, `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` on OS X, etc. works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must insert the instrumentation routine within the binary file. A good approach should be to insert those routines in a separate code segment and a separate data segment

What is a `binary file`? There is a *big* difference between doing this for a relocable (`ET_REL`) object file, vs. doing this for a fully linked executable (`ET_EXEC`)or shared library (`ET_DYN`).

> could you explain how to accomplish this?

For an `ET_REL`, it should be fairly straight-forward: you read the file header, which points to section headers, which tells you where `.data` and `.text` sections are. You then write a new file, extending the sections you want, copying everything else, and adjusting the section headers to reflect new section offsets and sizes.

For an `ET_DYN` or `ET_EXEC`, the problem is very likely *too hard*: you'll need to adjust relocation tables, hash tables, program headers; keeping all the structures self-consistent and properly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

In a Black Hat presentation by Shaun Clowes, Shaun is taking two strategies regarding to making modifications in ELF executable:

- In file patch - doing it by extending the Segment
- In core patch (on the fly) - doing it by taking advantage on memory space 
  available due to Segment alignment.

It is called "Black Hat USA 2002 - Fixing/Making Holes in Binaries" (Youtube)