# Is there a way to intercept an internal glibc call?

Tags: linux, glibc, ld-preload

I am trying to use an old program (where only a binary is available) which simply gets stuck at IO on Debian Buster while working on systems with older glibc releases. Someone found out that the problem is tied to a glibc fix introduced via https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190

I have managed to compile a glibc with the fix commented and running the program with that glibc makes it working fine.

The system's glibc shows the two functions that the above fix changes so I assume they can be replaced by own ones that effectively undo the fix:

```
$ readelf -a /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep underflow
  1544: 000000000007ed60    86 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_str_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  1597: 0000000000074550   346 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __wunderflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  1604: 00000000000753d0  1603 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_wfile_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  2152: 000000000007c520   705 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  2216: 000000000007d420   258 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

I have also managed to intercept those functions with 
gdb.

So I have written a small shared library intercepting the changed functions. Unfortunately that does not work out because my replacement functions are never called. As a test I added replacments for `fread` and `fwrite` in the same way and *those* were called. So my general approach is working.

Some more details:
- the fix changes the two functions `_IO_new_file_underflow` in glibc's `iolib/fileops.c` and `_IO_old_file_underflow` in `iolib/oldfileops.c` 
- I have written two replacement functions that undo the fix and then call the original:

```
int
_IO_new_file_underflow (FILE *fp)
{
  int (*next)(FILE *fp) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "_IO_new_file_underflow");

  fprintf(stderr, "%s: called\n", __func__);

  if (fp->_flags & _IO_EOF_SEEN)
    fp->_flags &= ~_IO_EOF_SEEN;

  return next(fp);
}

int
_IO_old_file_underflow (FILE *fp)
{
  int (*next)(FILE *fp) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "_IO_old_file_underflow");

  fprintf(stderr, "%s: called\n", __func__);

  if (fp->_flags & _IO_EOF_SEEN)
    fp->_flags &= ~_IO_EOF_SEEN;

  return next(fp);
}
```

- compile that with `gcc -o x.so -shared x.c -ldl -fPIC`
- run the faulty program with `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/x.so faultyprogram`
- Result: the replacement functions are never called, the program fails.
- These symbols are in the .so file:

```
$ readelf -a x.so | grep underflow
     8: 000000000000118a   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_old_file_underflow
     9: 0000000000001115   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_new_file_underflow
    47: 0000000000001115   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_new_file_underflow
    50: 000000000000118a   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_old_file_underflow
```

In contrast to the above output from the system's glibc my version is lacking symbols so I also have added them via a linker version script:

```
$ cat version
VERSION {
GLIBC_2.2.5 {
         global: *;
};

$ gcc -o x.so -shared x.c -ldl -fPIC version
$ readelf -a x.so | grep underflow
     8: 0000000000001115   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_new_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
     9: 000000000000118a   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_old_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
    48: 0000000000001115   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_new_file_underflow
    51: 000000000000118a   117 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _IO_old_file_underflow
```

But that does not work, either.

Running ldd on the program with `LD_DEBUG=all` I can see many symbols but the two in question were not resolved by the linker. I guess this is because they are treated as some kind of private functions in glibc. But if that is true why are the symbols visible at all in libc.so.6?

I am now wondering if I am missing something essential here or if it is generally impossible to achieve an LD_PRELOAD replacement for the two functions in question.

Update: added gdb experience, fixed typo

Comment: Off: Maybe you should run this program in a Docker-container built with old gcc.

Comment: What happens if you just remove or rename those symbols in glibc using `objcopy`. If they are not there they cannot be called. So either you get a linker error (that will tell you why your replacement symbols are not found) or your replacement symbols will be called.

Comment: Well, I tried that but using objcopy -N the symbols in question do not seem to be removable. The output file is identical to the inputfile.

Comment: "The system's glibc ..." -- which "the system" is that from? Debian Buster or some other? AFAICT, Debian Buster uses GLIBC-2.28, and the functions were marked private and stopped being exported much earlier than that (I have 2.15, and the functions are already private there).

Comment: @DanielJunglas `obcopy` can not easily modify fully-linked ELF binaries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732018/50617

Comment: @EmployedRussian yes, it's Debian Buster